# Segfault with arrow operator in c running chdir then printing

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, operator-keyword

```
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct test{
 int app;
}test;

int main()
{
int fi;
FILE* fp;
test* banned;
banned->app=2;
fi=chdir("/home");
    printf("%d", fi);
return 0;
}
```

This is part of a larger program. I need to be able to navigate to a directory from a read in file, and put the information into a struct. However whenever this program compiles it seg faults. Running gdb on a gcc compile

```
#0  0x08048421 in main ()
```

Is this an issue with the compiler or is something missing in the code to enable this?

Note: This has been solved I was a complete moron and tried to pull a rabbot out of a hat I just concieved of in my head... otherwise known as I didnt tie my reference to an actual value so compiler threw a fit. The solution was creating a "real struct" and then having the reference pointer point to that via reference=&normalpointer thanks for the help

Also as much as id love to use the struct without reference, I need to pass this into different functions. But the mentioned solutions are better than what im doing

Comment: "it seg faults" -- Gee, what a surprise, `banned` having a well defined value and all.

Comment: `banned` not initialized. change to `test banned; banned.app=2;`

Comment: You haven't allocated any space for banned.

Comment: @JimBalter I got a good chuckle out of your comment, but give the guy a break. We all have to start somewhere. :-)

Comment: Thanks for that. Just wrote a giant input function, rewrote it and found a problem line. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @MikeHolt There are better places to start than with unassigned pointers. Note from the OP's edit that he already knows enough.

Answer (score 2):

You are writing down an uninitialized pointer because you have defined `banned` as a pointer to a struct of type `test`, rather than an instance of type `test`. Change `test* banned` to `test banned`. Youll then use `.` rather than `->` to access the members of `banned`, e.g. `banned.app=2`.

Comment: And then `banned->app=2` should change to `banned.app=2`.

Comment: @MikeHolt Right. Editing my answer.

Comment: The reason for the reference was so it could be passed to a function and modified, in any case I found the solution, creating a real item and then assigning the pointer to it via pointerstruct = &normalstruct; works wonders

Comment: @user3542874 There's no difference between passing `pointerstruct` and passing `&normalstruct` ... in both cases the function will modify `normalstruct`